# Appropriate way to forward rvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++11, move, forward

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void bar(const std::string& str)
{
    cout << "const str - " << str << endl;
}

void bar(std::string&& str)
{
    cout << "str - " << str << endl;
}

void foo(std::string&& str)
{
    bar(str);
}


int main()
{
    foo("Hello World");
}
```

In the above code the `void bar(const std::string& str)` overload gets called. If I want the `void bar(std::string&& str)` overload to be called I either have to write `bar(std::move(str));` or `bar(std::forward<std::string>(str));`

Obviously the forward code is longer, but it makes more sense to me. My question is what is more commonly used and preferred. Writing `bar(std::forward(str));` would be the best solution imo, but that is not an option :)

Comment: You can move it, forward should be used in templated code when you can't be sure if it's rvalue or lvalue reference. :) In templated code && mean universal reference, which can be either rvalue or lvalue.

Comment: @Melko If you make your comment an answer, I can accept it :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Citing from *Effective Modern C++*

> From a purely technical perspective, the answer is yes: std::forward can do it all. std::move isn’t necessary. Of course, neither function is really necessary, because we could write casts everywhere, but I hope we agree that that would be,well, yucky. std::move’s attractions are convenience, reduced likelihood of error, and greater clarity.

Using `std::move` here

```
void foo(std::string&& str)
{
    bar(str);
}
```

will return `str` as an rvalue reference (which is exactly what you're trying to achieve) while using `std::forward` would return either an lvalue reference (which you're not interested in) or an rvalue reference (thus equivalent in this case to `std::move`). Obviously using none would just keep calling the `const std::string& str` one since `str` is an lvalue in that function.

Bottom-line: they would do the same thing but using `std::move` is preferred since

- It avoids explicitly specifying template arguments
- It is more idiomatic
- It goes straight to the point: `std::forward` is not intended to be used that way (cfr. [Universal references](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers)) or in that context although it would surely work

I might agree that "*I'm forwarding this rvalue reference to the other function*" might make sense as a standalone sentence but it kind of misses the point of the matter. You could re-wire your brain to think it like "*Keep 'moving' this rvalue reference to the other function*"

Also possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18214825/1938163

Answer (score 7):

You can move it whenever you are sure it's an rvalue reference.

Forward should be used in templated code when you can't be sure if it's rvalue or lvalue reference. :)

In templated code && mean universal reference, which can be either rvalue or lvalue.

Also note, that std::move is casting it without any check, unlike forward, so while forward is safer if you are not sure what should you do, move is faster.